# jquery .ajax() unexpected ;

Tags: ajax, jquery

trying to do some low-level ajax that hits url in the background but does nothing on the client side. Here is the code:

```
can_id = $(this).attr('id');            
$.ajax({
    url:"savethis.php",
    data:"q=0&can_id="+can_id;
});
```

but I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
```

When I comment out the ajax() portion the error goes away. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: The error is telling you what the problem is. There is a `;` where there isn't supposed to be. So remove the `;` after `can_id`...

Comment: bah, thanks. Staring at the screen too long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a semicolon at the end of can_id. Remove it

```
data:"q=0&can_id="+can_id**;**
```

Comment: I agree. Complement: semicolon is used as separator for statements in javascript. Hence, @themerlinproject should use it only ending a statement, declaring a function or a variable and stuff, NOT declaring parameters inside a function call :)